# How to hide overlay on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code, what i want is to hide overlay after mouse hover, and what is happening is its staying active until i remove mouse hover on the image. is there any one can solve this problem

```css
.upper {position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden; background: #ddd; opacity: 0.5; transition: .2s ease; border-radius: 100%;}
.maine:hover .upper {width: 150%; height: 150%;}
.maine {position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
.upper:after {width 0; height: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="maine">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="upper"> heading </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you probably got more code to paste as this is lacking the html. what element is that you're hovering on?

Comment: right mistakenly i forgot to paste complete code. my bad

Comment: i think u didn't read my question properly.

Comment: Is the transparent circle supposed to appear on mouseover, then disappear once its expanded? Please explain the desired effect.

Comment: yep, that's exactly what i want..

Comment: The `heading` will not show with the above as it will disappear with the expanded white circle. Is that intended?

Comment: yes, heading wont be visible once it disappeared,

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that you want and made without using `@keyframes`.

```css
.maine {position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
.upper {position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; background: #ddd; transition-property: width, height; opacity: 0.5; transition: .4s ease; border-radius: 100%;}
.maine:hover .upper {width: 150%; height: 150%; opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="maine">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="upper"> heading </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep heading visible it should be a solution..!

```css
.maine {position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
.upper {position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; background: #ddd; transition-property: width, height; opacity: 0.5; transition: .4s ease; border-radius: 100%;}
.maine:hover .upper {width: 150%; height: 150%; opacity: 0; }
.heading {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding-top: 30%; text-align: center; display: none; transition: all .2s linear !important;}
.maine:hover .heading {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="maine">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="upper"></div>
    <di class="heading"><h2>Heading</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops, no what i want is when i hover the image a "grey" overlay should appear and disappear automatically, and what happening is its not disappearing after hover, its making me remove my mouse from the image in order to disappear the overlay.

Comment: i don't think that u understand what my question is. anyway ur just a bit away from the solution.. just look at the "Brett answer" that is exactly what i wanted. btw thanks for reminding me that "Position" could work to void disappearing the heading. thanks rohit

Answer (score 1):

Either use keyframe or this solution:

```
.maine:hover .upper:active,
.maine:hover .upper:focus,
.maine:hover .upper:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution will be switch to an `animation`.

```css
.upper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.upper-background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(251, 251, 251, 0.5);
}

.upper-inner {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.maine:hover .upper-background {
  animation: expand 0.6s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.maine:hover .upper-inner {
  animation: showText 0.3s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.maine {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes showText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
  }
  95% {
    width: 150%;
    height: 150%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 150%;
    height: 150%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="maine">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="upper">
      <div class="upper-background"></div>
      <div class="upper-inner">NAME</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about the `heading` text? Is that supposed to remain showing?

Comment: well, do we have any option we can disappear the overlay but the heading text wont disappear along with it?..

Comment: Yep, definitely doable. I'll update the solution when I have some time.

Comment: Thanks Brett, i will be waiting for your response.

Comment: Made a few updates to show the text at the end. Complicates it a bit, and there might be better ways to handle it, but seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove overlay, remove transform property from `.upper` class

```css
.upper {position: absolute; top: 50%; bottom: 0; left: 50%; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden; background: #ddd; opacity: 0.5; transition: .2s ease; border-radius: 100%;}
.maine:hover .upper {width: 150%; height: 150%;}
.maine {position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
.upper:after {width 0; height: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="maine">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="upper"> heading </div>
</div>
</div>
```